# ¿De dónde sale este "record[id]"? ¿Esto es un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

No entiendo del todo qué hace esa función, ¿me podrían explicar?

Ejercicio de freeCodeCamp, esto dice:

> Colección de discos
> Se te da un objeto literal que representa una parte de tu colección de álbumes musicales. Cada álbum tiene un número de id único como clave y varias otras propiedades. No todos los álbumes tienen una información completa.
> Empiezas con una función updateRecords la cual toma un objeto literal, records, que contiene el álbum musical de la colección, un id, prop (como artist o tracks), y value. Completa la función usando las reglas siguientes para modificar el objeto pasado a la función.
> Tu función siempre debe devolver el objeto de colección de registros completo.
> Si prop no es tracks y value no es una cadena vacía, actualiza o establece la propiedad prop del album a value.
> Si prop es tracks pero el álbum no tiene una propiedad tracks, crea un arreglo vacío y agrégale value a él.
> Si prop es tracks y value no es una cadena vacía, agrega value al final del arreglo de tracks existentes del álbum.
> Si value es una cadena vacía, elimina esa propiedad prop del álbum.
> Nota: Se usa una copia del objeto recordCollection para las pruebas.

---

Y lo siguente que van a ver, es la respuesta correcta que copié y pegué pero no logro comprenderla cuando llega la parte de `record[id][prop]`, ¿esto es un arreglo? ¿De dónde sale?

// Configuración

```
const recordCollection = {

  2548: {

    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',

    artist: 'Bon Jovi',

    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },

  2468: {

    albumTitle: '1999',

    artist: 'Prince',

    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },

  1245: {

    artist: 'Robert Palmer',

    tracks: []
  },

  5439: {

    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }

};
```

> // Cambia solo el código debajo de esta línea (PARA STACKOVERLOW: AQUÍ LA RESPUESTA QUE COPIÉ Y NO ENTIENDO, QUÉ HACE ESTA FUNCIÓN DE DÓNDE SALE ESA RECORD[ID][PROP])//

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {


  if (prop !== 'tracks' && value !== "") {


    records[id][prop] = value;


  } else if (prop === "tracks" && records[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false) {


    records[id][prop] = [value];


  } else if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {


    records[id][prop].push(value);


  } else if (value === "") {


    delete records[id][prop];

  }
  return records;

}

updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si analizas la función:

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
```

Simplemente:

- `records` es el objeto completo, o sea, todos los discos;
- `id` es un parámetro, que pasas para determinar qué `id` se va a actualizar;
- `prop` es la propiedad que pasas, para verificar si la misma es `tracks` o no (según la lógica de tu función)
- `value` es el valor que pasas para establecerlo como valor de la propiedad si fuera preciso modificar el objeto

Esto:

```
records[id][prop] = value;
```

Significa lo siguiente: *haz que en el objeto `records` cuyo `id` sea el valor de `id`  y cuya propiedad sea `prop`, su valor sea ahora `value`*.

Así, si tú llamas la función de este modo:

```
updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
```

El objeto se modificará en el nodo `5439`, quedando así:

```
  5439: {

    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold',
    artist: 'ABBA'
  }
```

Para entender cómo funcionan los objetos y sus propiedades, convendría que leas el apartado [**Trabajando con objetos** en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).